# why it is not showing any error and it is also not inserting data into ms access file using C #?

Tags: c#

I am new on c# and i am facing problem. i made two buttons, one for case another for credit card. when i click on button, my data is not inserting into ms access file.why is it not showing any error and how can i fix it ?

```
private void CashButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveOrder((int)PaymentTypes.Cash);
}

private void CreditCardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveOrder((int)PaymentTypes.CreditCard);
}

private void SaveOrder(int paymentType)
{
try
{
    string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
    {
        conn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Orders](OrderNummber,TransactionDate,ClientName,TotalAmount,PaymentType) VALUES(@OrderNummber,@TransactionDate,@ClientName,@TotalAmount,@PaymentType)",conn))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNummber",OrderNumberTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionDate",TransactionDateDateTimePicker.Value.Date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName",ClientNameTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmount",Convert.ToDecimal(TotalAmountTextBox.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentType", paymentType);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in CartDataGridView.Rows)
                    { 
                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [OrdersItems](OrderNumber,Quantity,UnitPrice,TotalPrice) VALUES(@OrderNumber,@Quantity,@UnitPrice,@TotalPrice)", conn))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", OrderNumberTextBox.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value));
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice",Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["UnitPrice"].Value));
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["TotalPrice"].Value));

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                        MessageBox.Show("Order is processed successfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

}

Comment: That's because you silently catch all exceptions.

Comment: And empty catch is not helpful detecting errors.

Comment: If that was your original code I would strongly advice on proper code indenting, it could be far more readable.

Comment: but it must insert data into access file.

Comment: Unless you get into the catch because and exception is raised and you did not notice. Set a breakpint in that catch, or put a `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);`

Comment: i tried MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); but still not working

Comment: But did an error message popup? You should consider editing the question and defining "not working". Also I would store the amount of rows affected in your first insert to know if it actually did anything. `int ordersInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); if (ordersInserted == 0) { /* Something went wrong */}`

Comment: Add the `PaymentTypes` enum declaration to your question and check if the values of the enumeration do match with the spected database `PaymentType` column values. Is there a table of payments? what data does it have?

Comment: `i tried MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); but still not working` Please update your question to reflect your **current** code, including that change.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Coding\Microsoft Access\Northwind.mdb";

    string fstName  = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    string lstName  = textBox2.Text.Trim();
    string adres = textBox3.Text.Trim();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO MyExcelTable (FName, LName, Address) VALUES (@FName, @LName, @Address)")
    {
        Connection = conn
    };

    conn.Open();

    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        // you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = adres;

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(@"Data Added");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + "\n" + ex.Message);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Connection Failed");
    }
}
   }
}
```

This will definitely work.  Just change the connection string and the variables to suit your needs.